# "Never have listened to something THAT heavy"

Tags: grammar, meaning

So "That" in the sentence expresses that this something is very heavy? Or does the sentence mean ive never listened to any heavy songs?

Comment: It's the word ***that*** that makes the difference. Without it, *[**I**] never have listened to something heavy* (or more likely, *...to **anything** heavy*) would mean speaker has never listened to any heavy songs at all. But ***that*** means there must be *some specific **very** heavy song* being referred to (heavier than anything speaker has ever listened to before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have missed the word "I".

The phrase in the title isn't a sentence I think you might have mistyped it.  "Never have **I** listened to something that heavy" is correct English (and means the same)  But "I have never listened to something that heavy." would be better (clearer, more idiomatic)

Assuming that, You could paraphrase this as

> I've never listened to something as heavy as that.

It means "I've listened to things that are less heavy, but I've not listened to things that are the equal of that, or heavier than that."

You may infer from this that the music referred to is especially heavy.

Comment: so the sentence in the title is wrong?

Comment: It's not a sentence.... I think you might have mistyped it.  "Never have **l** listened to something that heavy" is correct English (and means the same)

Comment: ah, I thought its not a big deal